# Binding a single ion-item using Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2

If I have a list I can use `ion-item` like this:

```
<ion-card ion-item *ngFor="#item of previous" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
```

How can I use `ion-item` in the same wa with just a single item?

The docs aren't very clear on this, http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/item/Item/

Comment: Please add more details about what you actually try to accomplish. If you remove `*ngFor...` then you have just one `<ion-card>`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but it seems to me you want to have a list inside your ``ion-card`` as described here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#card-list Please be more specific with your question

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're attempting to do. If you want to show only a single item bind your item to a single object, not an array of objects. E.g.

You'll need to define your single item in your component:

```
export class YourComponent {
  //...
  items: <Array>;
  singleItem: any;
  //...
  constructor() {
    //...
    this.singleItem = {
      data: "foo"
    };
  }
}
```

And then simply bind your data to your element:

```
<ion-card ion-item (click)="itemTapped($event, singleItem)">
  {{ singleItem.data }}
</ion-card>
```

`*ngFor="#x of y"` is only reserved for iterating over arrays in Angular2, so it's not necessary for a single item.

I did this with your examples, if you want to set the `singleItem` data to that of the previous page. In order to pass data/items between pages look at [Ionic2 NavParams](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavParams/) and [Ionic2 Navigation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation).